# Delivery status to app-messages(like fb message/whatsapp message) in android app

Tags: android, ios

I am implementing messaging to my app and want to know if message got delivered to app and if yes, when is it delivered. Whatsapp and many other messaging apps have this functionality.

We sometimes broadcast SOS information and want to send SMS also if the user is offline and doesnt receive the message within 10 minutes.

Do I use

```
cm.getActiveNetworkInfo
```

for this purpose?

Comment: Did you see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589642/sms-delivery-report-in-android

Comment: I am not asking about SMS here. I am sending a message from server to client.